# debsecan reports vulnerable packages despite installed fixes

Tags: debian, security

I have an up-to-date debian stable (bullseye) install, complete with `debian-security`:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/              bullseye          main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/              bullseye-updates  main contrib non-free

deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/               bullseye          main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ bullseye-security main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/               bullseye-updates  main contrib non-free
```

I was surprised to see so fixed many CVEs when I ran `debsecan`:

```
$ debsecan --suite bullseye --only-fixed | wc -l
310
```

---

I took a look at a handful of packages and I found that I already had the fixed versions installed.  In this case, `libc-bin 2.31-13+deb11u4` seems to have a fix for CVE-2021-33574.  I have `+deb11u5` installed, so I'm don't understand why this CVE is being flagged on my system.

```
$ debsecan --suite bullseye --only-fixed --format detail
CVE-2021-33574 (fixed)
  The mq_notify function in the GNU C Library (aka glibc) versions 2.32  ...
  installed: libc-bin 2.31-13+deb11u5
             (built from glibc 2.31-13+deb11u5)
  fixed in unstable: glibc 2.32-1 (source package)
  fixed on branch:   glibc 2.28-10+deb10u2 (source package)
  fixed on branch:   glibc 2.31-13+deb11u3 (source package)
  fixed on branch:   glibc 2.31-13+deb11u4 (source package)
  fixed on branch:   glibc 2.32-0experimental0 (source package)
  fix is available for the selected suite (bullseye)
```

Is this a false-positive, or am I interpreting these results wrong?

The issue doesn't just apply to fixed packages.  In this case `xxd` has a fix in `8.1.0875-5+deb10u4`, while I have `8.2.2434-3+deb11u1` installed.  In this case, could it be that the fix was applied to `unstable`, `testing` and `oldstable` while skipping `stable`?

```
$ debsecan --suite bullseye | wc -l
2102
$ debsecan --suite bullseye  --format detail
CVE-2022-3324
  Stack-based Buffer Overflow in GitHub repository vim/vim prior to 9.0. ...
  installed: xxd 2:8.2.2434-3+deb11u1
             (built from vim 2:8.2.2434-3+deb11u1)
  fixed in unstable: vim 2:9.0.0626-1 (source package)
  fixed on branch:   vim 2:8.1.0875-5+deb10u3 (source package)
  fixed on branch:   vim 2:8.1.0875-5+deb10u4 (source package)
$
```